Language change from DE to EN is not working
I have implemented a language change in my project but it won't work. In fact the varibles in the messages.properties are grey. And the Thymeleaf implementation in the index says, that there is nothing to go to:
My WebConfig:
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
@Bean
  public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.GERMAN);
    return slr;
  }
@Bean
  public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    lci.setParamName("lang");
    return lci;
  }
@Override
  public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
  }
}

index:
<li class="nav-item" th:if="${canDeleteHotel}">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openPopup('http://localhost:8080/deletedhotel')" style="color: #ffffff;">
                            <span th:text="#{deleted.hotels}">Gelöschte Hotels</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>```

application-properties:
spring.messages.basename=messages
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false

I did also configure the properies accordingly - one named messages.properties, the other messages_de.properties.

I don't know where I went wrong

I did all the files but it still is not working. I can see that the URL is changing but the text doesn't

